# Memory error. A better way to count possibilities? 12 million is too many?

Tags: list, dictionary, out-of-memory, combinations, flatmap

Maybe I should compile the list at different times so it doesn't load all at once?

Everything worked until I added row 4 and 5, so I'm not sure it's a coding issue. Seems more like a noobie issue, not knowing what tools are my disposal.

The overall goal is to generate a combination of numbers (0-100) in 5 rows. Without any duplicates. 1,2,3,4,5 to 1,2,3,4,6 ect ect until all combinations are completed.

I've attached the code below ::

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val startButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.startButton)
    val possibilities = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.possibilities)

        val rowOne  = listOf("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42","43","44","45","46","47","48","49","50","51","52","53","54","55","56","57","58","59","60","61","62","63","64","65","66","67","68","69","70")
        val rowTwo  = listOf("2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42","43","44","45","46","47","48","49","50","51","52","53","54","55","56","57","58","59","60","61","62","63","64","65","66","67","68","69","70")
        val rowThree = listOf("3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42","43","44","45","46","47","48","49","50","51","52","53","54","55","56","57","58","59","60","61","62","63","64","65","66","67","68","69","70")
        val rowFour = listOf("4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42","43","44","45","46","47","48","49","50","51","52","53","54","55","56","57","58","59","60","61","62","63","64","65","66","67","68","69","70")
        val rowFive = listOf("5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42","43","44","45","46","47","48","49","50","51","52","53","54","55","56","57","58","59","60","61","62","63","64","65","66","67","68","69","70")

        val combinations =
            rowOne.flatMap { rowOne ->
                rowTwo.flatMap { rowTwo ->
                    rowThree.flatMap { rowThree ->
                        rowFour.flatMap { rowFour ->
                            rowFive.map { rowFive -> "$rowFour $rowFive" }
                        }.map { resultThree -> "$resultThree $rowThree" }
                    }.map { resultTwo -> "$resultTwo $rowTwo" }
                }.map { resultOne -> "$resultOne $rowOne" }
            }.toList()


    startButton.setOnClickListener {
            possibilities.text = ("${(combinations).size} Possibilities")}
```

Comment: You mean 1,452,361,680?

Comment: Then that would definitely be the problem. 5 rows of 70, no duplicates, should be 12 million...ish.